# How to solve this Partial Decomposition fraction?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

I was doing my laplace transform revision and I came across this problem. How to decompose this partial fraction ?

$$ \frac{145s}{(s^2+4)(s^2+4s+13)} +\frac{9s+55}{s^2+4s+13}$$

How to write the partial decomposition form and I much appreciated if you can show me the full step. I really forgot the partial decomposition.
The given answer is $$\frac{16}{s^2+4} + \frac{9s}{s^2+4} + \frac{3}{s^2+4s+13}$$

Comment: For the record, I suggested an edit removing the tag "calculus", but [it was rejected](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1998295).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$s^2+4$ and $s^2+4s+13$ are irreducible quadratics, so you’re really just decomposing

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{145s}{(s^2+4)(s^2+4s+13)}&=\frac{As+B}{s^2+4}+\frac{Cs+D}{s^2+4s+13}\\\\
&=\frac{(As+B)(s^2+4s+13)+(Cs+D)(s^2+4)}{(s^2+4)(s^2+4s+13)}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Equate numerators:

$$\begin{align*}
145s&=(As+B)(s^2+4s+13)+(Cs+D)(s^2+4)\\
&=(A+C)s^3+(4A+B+D)s^2+(13A+4B+4C)s+(13B+4D)\;,
\end{align*}$$

so

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
&A+C=0\\
&4A+B+D=0\\
&13A+4B+4C=145\\
&13B+4D=0\;.
\end{align*}\right.\tag{1}$$

Solving the system $(1)$ is mildly annoying but routine; the solution is $A=9,B=16,C=-9$, and $D=-52$. Thus,

$$\frac{145s}{(s^2+4)(s^2+4s+13)}=\frac{9s+16}{s^2+4}-\frac{9s+52}{s^2+4s+13}\;,$$

and

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{145s}{(s^2+4)(s^2+4s+13)}+\frac{9s+55}{s^2+4s+13}&=\frac{9s+16}{s^2+4}+\frac3{s^2+4s+13}\\\\
&=\frac{9s}{s^2+4}+\frac{16}{s^2+4}+\frac3{s^2+4s+13}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Brian thanks for your great effort and help. You did very well. Thank you very much

Comment: @Garett: You’re very welcome.

Comment: you have any facebook account or email. I like to add you as my friend.